# Android: Google Sign In - credential token list is always empty

Tags: android, google-signin, android-googleapiclient, google-smartlockpasswords, googlesigninaccount

I'm implementing the google smart lock sign in to automatically log a user in without input, however I'm running into the problem that the token list (getIdTokens) returned in the credential object token list is always empty even after a "successful" connection. At what point is the credential object actually populated with a token list?

I'm using this example to build the code:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-credentials/blob/master/credentials-signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/example/credentialssignin/MainActivity.java#L101

```
private void googleSilentSignIn() {
        // Try silent sign-in with Google Sign In API
        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr =
                Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {
            GoogleSignInResult gsr = opr.get();
            handleGoogleSignIn(gsr);
        } else {
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    handleGoogleSignIn(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }


 private void handleGoogleSignIn(GoogleSignInResult gsr) {
        Timber.i("handleGoogleSignIn:" + (gsr == null ? "null" : gsr.getStatus()));

        boolean isSignedIn = (gsr != null) && gsr.isSuccess();
        if (isSignedIn) {
            // Display signed-in UI
            GoogleSignInAccount gsa = gsr.getSignInAccount();
            String status = String.format("Signed in as %s (%s)", gsa.getDisplayName(),
                    gsa.getEmail());

            Timber.d("handleGoogleSignIn %s", status);

            // Save Google Sign In to SmartLock
            Credential credential = new Credential.Builder(gsa.getEmail())
                    .setAccountType(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
                    .setName(gsa.getDisplayName())
                    .setProfilePictureUri(gsa.getPhotoUrl())
                    .build();

            saveCredentialIfConnected(credential);

            Timber.d("handleGoogleSignIn: credential tokens was %s", credential.getIdTokens().toString());
}
}

  private void requestCredentials(final boolean shouldResolve, boolean onlyPasswords) {
    Timber.d("requestCredentials");

    CredentialRequest.Builder crBuilder = new CredentialRequest.Builder()
            .setPasswordLoginSupported(true);

    if (!onlyPasswords) {
        crBuilder.setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE);
    }

    Auth.CredentialsApi.request(mGoogleApiClient, crBuilder.build()).setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<CredentialRequestResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(CredentialRequestResult credentialRequestResult) {
                    Status status = credentialRequestResult.getStatus();

                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        // Auto sign-in success

                        Timber.d("requestCredentials:onsuccess with token size %d", credentialRequestResult.getCredential().getIdTokens().size() );

                        handleCredential(credentialRequestResult.getCredential());
                    } else if (status.getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED
                            && shouldResolve) {
                        // Getting credential needs to show some UI, start resolution
                        resolveResult(status, RC_CREDENTIALS_READ);
                    }
                }
            });
}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (!mIsResolving) {
        requestCredentials(true /* shouldResolve */, false /* onlyPasswords */);
    }
}


private void handleCredential(Credential credential) {

        Timber.i("handleCredential with %s %s %s %s %s", credential.getId(), credential.getAccountType(), credential.getGeneratedPassword(), credential.getName(), credential.getPassword());

        mCredential = credential;

        if (IdentityProviders.GOOGLE.equals(credential.getAccountType())) {
            // Google account, rebuild GoogleApiClient to set account name and then try
            buildGoogleApiClient(credential.getId());
            googleSilentSignIn();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getIdTokens()` on a credential object should return a list containing an OpenID Connect ID token when the credential has been retrieved via the `Auth.CredentialsApi.request()` or `Auth.CredentialsApi.getHintPickerIntent()` method and the credential corresponds to a Google Account signed in on a device running Play Services 8+

Note that `.setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)` should be included when constructing the request:

```
    CredentialRequest request = new CredentialRequest.Builder()
            .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
            .setSupportsPasswordLogin(true)
            .build();
```

or when getting a hint if no saved credential is available:

```
    HintRequest hintRequest = new HintRequest.Builder()
            .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
            .setEmailAddressIdentifierSupported(true)
            .build();
```

There won't be an ID token if the credential is constructed with the `Credential.Builder` (as shown in part of the code in the question), or if the credential does not match the email address of a Google Account on the device.

So some things to check:

- test on a device running the latest version of Play Services (8.4)
- ensure that the retrieved credential matches a Google Account signed in on the device and that the account is in good standing (is in sync, receiving emails, does not need password to be re-entered, etc.)
- verify that the credential retrieved has been previously saved in the app or associated website (via Chrome password manager), or came from a `HintRequest` built with `.setAccountType(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)`

If you still have trouble getting an ID token, leave a comment with the details of your environment.

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution in googlesamples/android-credentials on GitHub by adding **.setIdTokenRequested(true)**

```
CredentialRequest credentialRequest = new CredentialRequest.Builder()
                            .setPasswordLoginSupported(true)
                            .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
                            .setIdTokenRequested(true)
                            .build();
```